# What is the difference between String... variable and String varible[] in Java?

Tags: java

we can have two declaration for String array

1>String... sampleStringArray;

2>String sampleStringArray[];

can anyone tell me the difference

Comment: here is something that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288799/difference-between-a-string-and-an-array-of-characters

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973505/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is an example of [varargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax#Varargs) and the wikipedia notes *These values will be available inside the method as an array*, must be the last parameter in a given method, and is otherwise accessed as an array (also it wasn't added to the language until Java 5).